# JavaScript/JQurey Como puedo mostrar datos dinamicos en un div, con sus estilos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

En mi `html` tengo un `div`, dentro tengo un `h3` y un `img`, lo que yo quiero es hacer un `append` con datos precargados desde mi `js`, en el cual utilizo `ajax`, que me trae de `sql` los datos que quiero precargar.

Mi problema es al hacer el `append`, que me muestra los datos dinámicos pero me parece que tengo un problema con las comillas, y tengo que acortar mi `url` de imagen, me parece... Mis `div` tienen estilo en mi `css`, pero no se si al meterlo al `append` se mantienen!

Paso mi código tal cual como está:

```js
function ObtengoDatosYRutaFoto(NombreSeccion, NombreCategoria, NombreEstilo, NombreMarca, NumTalle) {
//este es el metodo donde obtengo los datos
    NombreSeccion = $.trim(NombreSeccion);
    NombreCategoria = $.trim(NombreCategoria);
    NombreEstilo = $.trim(NombreEstilo);
    NombreMarca = $.trim(NombreMarca);
    NumTalle = $.trim(NumTalle);

    var dir = "ObtengoDatosConFoto";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: api + dir + "?NombreSeccion=" + NombreSeccion + "&NombreCategoria=" + NombreCategoria + "&NombreEstilo=" + NombreEstilo + "&NombreMarca=" + NombreMarca + "&NumTalle=" + NumTalle,
        success: function(datos) {
            var d = datos;
            for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
                $("#contenedor_busqueda").append('<div class="divConImg">' +
                    +'<h3 class="infoImg">' + d[i].Fabricante + "/" + d[i].Articulo + "/" + d[i].Descripcion + "/" + d[i].Color + '</h3>' +
                    +'<img src=' + d[i].Ruta + ' border="1" width="200px" height="200px">' +
                    +'</div>')
                    //ACA ESTA MI PROBLEMA
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });


}
```

```css
#contenedor_busqueda {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    letter-spacing: -1em;
}

.divConImg {
    width: 39.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: center;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}

.infoImg {
    text-align: center;
    width: 83.5%;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor_busqueda">
                <!--div class="divConImg">
                    <h3 class="infoImg"></h3>
                    <img src="" border="1" width="200px" height="200px">
                </div-->
  </div>
  
  Aca tengo comentado lo de adentro porque lo voy a poner en  mi append
```

Comment: Te faltan las comillas en esta linea `+'<img src="' + d[i].Ruta + '" border="1" width="200px" height="200px">' +`

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo uses [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings), así evitas la confusión con el *Entrecomillado*, intentalo de esta forma.

```js
function ObtengoDatosYRutaFoto(NombreSeccion, NombreCategoria, NombreEstilo, NombreMarca, NumTalle) {
//este es el metodo donde obtengo los datos
    NombreSeccion = $.trim(NombreSeccion);
    NombreCategoria = $.trim(NombreCategoria);
    NombreEstilo = $.trim(NombreEstilo);
    NombreMarca = $.trim(NombreMarca);
    NumTalle = $.trim(NumTalle);

    var dir = "ObtengoDatosConFoto";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: api + dir + "?NombreSeccion=" + NombreSeccion + "&NombreCategoria=" + NombreCategoria + "&NombreEstilo=" + NombreEstilo + "&NombreMarca=" + NombreMarca + "&NumTalle=" + NumTalle,
        success: function(datos) {
            var d = datos;
            for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
   $("#contenedor_busqueda").append(`<div class="divConImg">
  <h3 class="infoImg">${d[i].Fabricante} / ${d[i].Articulo} / ${d[i].Descripcion} / ${d[i].Color}</h3>
                    <img src="${d[i].Ruta}"  border="1" width="200px" height="200px">
                    </div>`);
                    //ACA ESTA MI PROBLEMA
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });


}
```

```css
#contenedor_busqueda {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    letter-spacing: -1em;
}

.divConImg {
    width: 39.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: center;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}

.infoImg {
    text-align: center;
    width: 83.5%;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor_busqueda">
                <!--div class="divConImg">
                    <h3 class="infoImg"></h3>
                    <img src="" border="1" width="200px" height="200px">
                </div-->
  </div>
  
  Aca tengo comentado lo de adentro porque lo voy a poner en  mi append
```